# Proxy setting for non-winhttp and IE applications on windows server

Tags: windows, proxy

I have an application on a Windows server (server1) that uses `http` to grab `xml` and wave files from another server. This works great on a local network. However we want to start using a cloud service to host the files and will need to use `https`, which is not supported on by the application on server1.

I set up a proxy on the local network using nodejs and set proxy settings on server1 using `netsh winhttp set proxy` command and the environment variable `http_proxy` and it works great with curl and browser traffic, but traffic initiated by the application and `Test-NetConnection` are not using the proxy.

Is there a way to force every application that uses port 80 traffic to use the proxy server?

Comment: Most of Windows stuff uses the system proxy defined in inetcpl.cpl. However some other programs might choose to not depend on it. Like Firefox or .NET Framework.

Comment: The application needs it's own proxy settings, independent of the operating system.